# What is "faster" spyder or jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spyder

Maybe it is to broad for this place, but I have to work on a huge database /dataframe with some text processing. The dataframes are stored on my computer as csv.

Is it faster in terms of runtime to use spyder or jupyter notebook?

I am mainly using: `pandas, nltk`

The outcome is only a csv file, which I have to store on my computer.

Comment: yeah risky question to ask on here. Without your code to bench mark I have no idea for your application. Personally I find Spyder easier to work with so am willing to take a computaional hit if there is one.

Comment: Shouldn't the execution speed be more or less independent of the IDE?

Comment: @Trilarion that is exactly the question, I dont care to run it in spyder or jupyter, I just want to save some time and pick the "faster" one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jupyter is basically a browser application, whereas spyder is a dedicated IDE. When I work with large datasets, I never use Jupyter as Spyder seems to run much faster. The only way to truly compare this would be to run/time the same script on both Spyder and Jupyter a couple of times, but in my experience Spyder always beats Jupyter when it comes to computation time.

EDIT: As @carlos mentions in his comment: "in principle both Spyder and Jupyter use the exact same technology to run your code. On top of that, we have a lot of customizations to improve user experience."

When testing, I noticed however that jupyter always runs slower. I think it has to do with how many resources your PC allocates to a browser versus an IDE.

Comment: Downvote without a comment is pretty pointless. Rather tell me how to improve the answer.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Just to add a bit of context to your answer: both Spyder and Jupyter use the exact same [technology](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/messaging.html) to run your code. On top of that, we have a lot of [customizations](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-kernels/blob/master/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py) to improve user experience. However, I think Spyder and Jupyter should equally fast in principle (but I've never tested that, as it seems you have).

Comment: Do you have a  time comparision with some runs? Which browser are you using?